# Article usage and of phrase

Tags: phrases, articles, general-vs-specific

Here are two examples:

1. A: I heard there were those in this town who collect the LP.
   B: Yes, over there, Tom and Gina. They are the collectors of the LP you are looking for.
2. In general, the collectors of the LP spend a lot of money on buying their LP records.

I reckon in 1, the definite article modifying 'collectors' make the word specific implying Tom and Gina.

What I am wondering about is whether it is okay to say that in 2, the word 'collectors' being modified by the definite article refers to collectors of the LP in general or not.

If it is not, should it be written, say; "In general, the collectors of the LP in France spend a lot of money on buying their LP records."

Comment: First, you would not say "of *the* LP*", you'd say "of LPs" as in "collectors of LPs". But after a couple of times, that gets clunky; more idiomatic is "LP collectors". Thus "LP collectors in France spend a lot of money on their hobby."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. '*The* collectors' can never be general: neither can '*the* LP'.
 So your phrase "The collectors of the LP in France" actually refers to those particular people who collect that particular LP (which you have presumably mentioned previously). Also note that *LP* without an s is singular, so has to be adjectival and placed before the noun. "LP collectors spend a lot of money" is grammatical: so is "Collectors of LPs have a lot of shelves".